# Reload a page just one time in angualrjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using `angularjs` and i want when the page was loaded then it was refreshed just one time, what i tried :

```
<script>
app.cp.register('userProfileController', function ($window) {
    debugger;
    function reload() {
        $window.location.reload();
    }
    reload();
});
```

but the page will refreshed  unlimited time in this way, what is the problem?

Comment: What would be the use case of this? Although @tommybananas gave you the correct answer i would challenge the need for this. I'm pretty sure you can avoid it in any case.

Answer (score 1):

When the page is refreshed everything is wiped and you are re-registering your controller and executing `reload()`, so yes it will keep happening.

In order to persist data between page refreshes, you can use [ngStorage](https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage):

```
app.cp.register('userProfileController', function ($window, $localStorage) {
  debugger;
  function reload() {
    $localStorage.hasReloaded = true;
    $window.location.reload();
  }
  if (!$localStorage.hasReloaded) reload();
});
```

Comment: thanks for answering, i try to use `ngstorage` as u said,but i have some problems, i describe this problem in:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38554425/ngstorage-in-angularjs-issue , plz help me if u can, thanks again