# ngStorage in angularjs issue

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, ng-storage

I want to use `ngstorage` in my project. so i install this package :

```
Install-Package gsklee.ngStorage
```

and it install successfully.then in my app i insert dependency:

```
  var app = angular.module("app", ['ngRoute', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ngAnimate', 'ngStorage'])
    .config(['$httpProvider', '$controllerProvider', '$routeProvider', function ($httpProvider, $controllerProvider, $routeProvider) {
        app.cp = $controllerProvider;
        $httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;
    }]);
```

and in the page i use it like this:

```
<script>
  app.cp.register('userProfileController', function ($window, $localStorage) {
    function reload() {
        $localStorage.hasReloaded = true;
        $window.location.reload();
    }
    debugger;
    if (!$localStorage.hasReloaded) {
        reload();
    }
});

</script>
```

but it doesn't work. and it gives me this error:

> Module 'ngstorage' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

what is the problem?

Comment: Case is important and it should be `ngStorage`, not `ngstorage`.

Comment: I did it before, but the problem persist. in some article i read that using `ngstorage` instead `ngstorage` for solution, but it doesn't work